# How i can draw arc between two points of fixed length

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

How i can draw arc between two points of fixed length in SpriteKit (Xcode)?
I try use:

```
addCurveToPoint:controlPoint1:controlPoint2:
```

But length is not fixed.

Comment: `addCurveToPoint` adds a bezier curve to the current point not an arc. Try `addArcWithCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:`

Comment: I need a line of fixed length.

Comment: If you need a line, don't use addCurveToPoint.  Use addLineToPoint.  If you need the line to be of fixed length, you'll have to do some math to ensure that the point you pass in is at the desired distance from the "current" point (set by moveToPoint).

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to explain exactly what you are trying to accomplish.